# Terminology for functions with preimage of finite cardinality?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, terminology

I'm dealing with a class of continuous functions $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the preimage of any $y \in f([0, 1])$ is of finite cardinality. I wonder whether there is a common terminology of such functions. Thanks!

Comment: A function with finite [fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics))?

Comment: If the cardinality of the preimages is constant (that is, if there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f^{-1}(\{y\})| = n$ for all $y \in [0, 1]$) I have heard the term $n$-to-1, though not very commonly.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks for the reply. I wonder whether there is a specific name for functions with finite fibers. For example, in differential geometry, we call curves with non-zero derivatives as `regular curve'.

Comment: Related: [A function that crosses each horizontal line only finitely many times](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1078534/13130). In classical real analysis the term [Banach indicatrix](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Banach+indicatrix%22) (of a given function, at a given point) refers to the cardinality of the inverse image under that function of the singleton consisting of that point (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68635/13130) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/206780/15780)), **(continued)**

Comment: so one could refer to this as a function with a finite Banach indicatrix at each point. However, this term might not be sufficiently well known for general usage.

Comment: The term 'finite-to-one' is a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve seen the term “finite-to-one” being used in topology. No reference that I can recall.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take the term `finite-to-one'.